# Nested foreach loop creating duplicate records with if condiotion - PHP Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-8, nested-loops

**Problem:** There are modules, users, and user_modules tables, where the admin can assign multiple modules with permissions to a user. Admin can update module's permission which is already assigned to that user, and the modules which are not assigned should be loaded on blade view on the same table.

**But the issue is data is duplicating**

*I am posting my code with images*

**AdminController:**

```
$modules = Module::all();
$user_modules = User_module::with('module')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
return view('admin/seller_assign_modules', compact('user','modules','user_modules'));
```

**seller_assign_modules.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Modules</th>
           <th>Add</th>
           <th>Edit</th>
           <th>View</th>
           <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                            
     @foreach ($user_modules as $user_mod)
           @foreach ($modules as $mod)
                                
                @if ($mod->id == $user_mod->module_id)
                     <tr>
                           <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->module->name}}</td>
                           <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->add}}</td>
                           <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->edit}}</td>
                           <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->view}}</td>
                           <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->del}}</td>
                     </tr> 
                @else
                     <tr>
                           <td scope="row">{{$mod->name}}</td>
                           <td scope="row"></td>
                           <td scope="row"></td>
                           <td scope="row"></td>
                           <td scope="row"></td>
                     </tr>
                @endif

         @endforeach
     @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**modules table:**

[image]

**user_modules table:**

[image]

**result on seller_assign_modules.blade.php**

[image]

**I NEED THIS:**

[image]

Comment: you dont need to loop modules since you fetch user_modules.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha, ok but i also want to show modules that are not in user_modules table but in modules table .

Comment: Do you have user relationship in modules model ?

Comment: not yet, still debugging it. you can suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below (this is not a good approach however)

```
$user_modules = User_module::with('module')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
//Get modules where user dont have records
$non_user_modules = Module::whereNotIn('id', (clone $user_modules)->pluck('module_id')->toArray())->get();
        
return view('admin/seller_assign_modules', compact('user','modules','user_modules','non_user_modules'));
```

Then in the blade

```
 @foreach ($user_modules as $user_mod)
     
                 <tr>
                       <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->module->name}}</td>
                       <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->add}}</td>
                       <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->edit}}</td>
                       <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->view}}</td>
                       <td scope="row">{{$user_mod->del}}</td>
                 </tr> 
          

 @endforeach

 @foreach ($non_user_modules as $non_user_module)
     
                 <tr>
                       <td scope="row">{{$non_user_module->name}}</td>
                       <td scope="row"></td>
                       <td scope="row"></td>
                       <td scope="row"></td>
                       <td scope="row"></td>
                 </tr>
          

  @endforeach
```

**Best approach you could do**

Make a relationship at Module model like `userModules()`

Then get Modules like below

```
$modulesWithUser = Module::with(['userModules' => function($userQuery){
            $userQuery->where('user_id',$user_id);
        }])->get();
```

Then loop `$modulesWithUser` in blade and access its relationship inside loop to show users permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with here is,`Module` has many`User_modules`, but you only need one.

So in this case, one approach is map a new property like `user_module` to each `Module`.

**AdminController**

```php
$modules = Module::all();
$userModeules = User_module::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

$modules = $modules->map(function($module) {
    $module->user_module = $userModules->firstWhere('module_id', $module->id);

    return $module;
});

return view(
    'admin/seller_assign_modules',
    compact('modules')
);
```

**seller_assign_modules.blade.php**

```php
<tbody>
  @foreach($mdules as $module)
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">{{ $module->name }}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{ optional($module->user_module)->add }}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{ optional($module->user_module)->edit }}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{ optional($module->user_module)->view }}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{ optional($module->user_module)->del }}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```